# Bus error when allocating data of structs to an array and then Writing to a .txt file

Tags: c, arrays

so for an assignment I have for class, we are supposed to prompt the user to enter a number of employees (say 5), which will then prompt them to input data for each employee (name, salary, and department), and then store pointers to the employee data in the array. After entry is complete, the program should print the data and write it to a text file. So for some reason, when I run the function, ./employees, I get "Bus error". Any clue why? If you need me to clarify anything, let me know. Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "struct.h"
#include "employees.h"
#include <readline/readline.h>
#include <readline/history.h>
#include <errno.h>

#define MAXLINE (100) // MAXLINE is maximum length of an input line.

int main() {
  char* inputline; // pointer to input line
  char name[MAXLINE];
  int salary;
  char empSalary[MAXLINE]; 
  char department[MAXLINE];
  int num; // Number of employees
  int i; // Loop counter
  char* employeeArray[num*3];
  FILE *outfile = fopen("employee.txt", "w"); // Open or create file for writing

  inputline = readline("Enter the total number of employees: "); // Read the input line.
  num = atoi(inputline);

  for (i = 1; i < num + 1; i++) {
    struct _Employee* emp = malloc(sizeof(struct _Employee));

    inputline = readline("Enter the name of the employee: "); // Read the input line
    sscanf(inputline, "%s", name); // reads formatted input from a string.

    inputline = readline("Enter the salary of the employee: "); // Read the input line

    if (sscanf(inputline, "%s", salary) == 1) {
      printf("Invalid salary. Try again!\n"); // Error message for if the salary is less than 0
      inputline = readline("Enter the salary of the employee: "); // Read the input line
      salary = atoi(inputline); // Converts inputline to an integer and sets salary to that value.
    }

    salary = atoi(inputline); // Converts inputline to an integer and sets salary to that value.

    if (salary < 0) {
      printf("Invalid salary. Try again!\n"); // Error message for if the salary is less than 0
      inputline = readline("Enter the salary of the employee: "); // Read the input line
      salary = atoi(inputline); // Converts inputline to an integer and sets salary to that value.
    }

    inputline = readline("Enter the department of the employee: "); // Read the input line
    sscanf(inputline, "%s", department); // reads formatted input from a string

    emp->name = strdup(name);
    emp->salary = salary;
    emp->department = strdup(department);

    sprintf(empSalary,"%d", salary);

    employeeArray[(i*3) - 3] = name; 
    employeeArray[(i*3) - 2] = empSalary;
    employeeArray[(i*3) - 1] = department;

    printEmployee(emp);

    printf("About to write to file.\n");

    if (outfile == NULL) {
      printf("[employee] %d The open was unsuccessful!\n", errno, strerror(errno));
      return 1;
    }

    else {
      outputData(outfile, name, empSalary, department);
    }
  }

  fclose(outfile);

  freeMemory(*employeeArray);
}

/* Writes the input data to a text file employee.txt
 * @param stream The file to be written to
 * @param name Name of the employee
 * @param empSalary Salary of the employee
 * @param department Department the employee works in
 */

void outputData(FILE *stream, char* name, char* empSalary, char* department) {
  FILE *outfile = fopen("employee.txt", "w"); // Open or create file for writing

  fprintf(outfile, "%s\n %s\n %s\n", *name, *empSalary, *department);
}

/* Frees the memory of the array
 * @param array The array to be de-allocated
 */

void freeMemory(char* array) {
  int i; // Loop counter

  for (i = 0; i < sizeof(array); i++) {
    free(&array[i]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem in the following:

in the `freeMemory` you are trying to free memory not allocated with appropriate function (`malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`).

`malloc` used once to allocate memory for `struct _Employee`, but pointer stored in `array` (the parameter of `freeMemory`) are obviously NOT are pointers to `_Employee`

moreover using free as

```
 free(&array[i]);
```

looks of itself wrong - you get the address of element (probably not the first - even if `array` has address received from something like `malloc( N * sizeof(char))` call of  `free(&array[i])` while `i > 0` lead to memory management fault (`free(array)` can be, and only if memory was allocated and not de-allocated before, and address that is send to `free` MUST BE the same address that was received from `malloc`).

**EDIT**:

The only solution can help - redesign of program (or better to say, design program before coding). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

In outputData() , give pointers for fprintf():

```
fprintf(outfile, "%s\n %s\n %s\n", name, 
    empSalary, department);
```

*EDIT:* oh ! seems to be lot more mistakes here and there:

- In `freeMemory()` : sizeof(array) is the size of the pointer (4 or 8), not the array capacity.
- Call `freeMemory(employeeArray)` not  `freeMemory(*employeeArray)`
- You can't free static (on-stack) pointers: name, empSalary and depatment **are not**  dynamic. However, emp's attributes *are*.
- And better, remove useless `freeMemory()` function.
- Unlucky construction mixing structures and (a false) 2-D string array.
- many other stuffs...

As a *good exercise* (and advice !): remove `employeeArray` from your code, it will become clearer.

I would also remove the emp's malloc() to stick to static structure and
correctly free `emp.name` and `emp.department` after use, before relooping.